# Block offensive images from all sites in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, is it possible to block all offensive images on all pages? I sometimes encounter images on some websites that I consider graphic or disturbing, and I want to block all images that are hidden by Google Image Search in its "moderate" Safe Search setting.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet! Seriously speaking, you're not going to find an automated way to deal with this simply because what you consider to be offensive is going to be different from everyone else. What if Google's standard for offensiveness (whatever that is) doesn't match yours?

Comment: @Insilico Yes, the Internet does contain some imagery that many people find disturbing or violent. That's why I'm wondering whether it's possible to block all images that are ordinarily filtered by Google Image Search. (Also, I'm not concerned about whether or not Google's standard for offensiveness matches mine - I just want to use Google's safesearch filter for images on all sites.)

Comment: "offensive" is seems a little bit subjective.

Comment: @Anderson Green: You probably can figure out a way to take advantage of Google's capabilities to your favor, but I'm pretty sure Google doesn't index every single image on the Internet, since IIRC there is in fact a human element part of the SafeSearch filter.

Comment: @Insilico Which human element are you referring to, specifically? This phrase seems ambiguous.

Comment: @Anderson Green: As in they have human beings sit down in front of a computer to review some of the images and they manually categorize the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parental control program (google it). They act as a proxy:you can define the list of what offends you (nudity, language, religion etc.) and the application blocks the content from being displayed. Most of these applications also learn in time, and improve the results, so you'll be exposed to less offensive material, and have less false-positives.

Comment: Do any of these parental control programs allow blocking of Safesearch-filtered images (or at least a community-edited image filter)?

Comment: @Anderson Green: I don't know of any parental control programs that have that kind of granularity in its filtering. It's usually at the site-level.

Comment: I wouldn't want to manually create a list of every gory/violent/disturbing image that I found on Wikipedia - some kind of automated filter would be better.

Comment: @Anderson Green: What kind of sites are you visiting that makes this such a problem in the first place? It seems to me you would have to actively seek out these kinds of things; certainly mainstream sites don't just put up these images without a "NSFW" warning or something.

Comment: @AndersonGreen you don't need to create a blacklist manually: these applications (I know a few, but I won't mention commercial solutions you could easily find on your own) come with a full, updateable list. In addition, they use all kinds of nudity-discerning algorithms to block certain content. They are used by corporations to block content for the entire network, or by parents to control a home network.